# DateTime Picker config in chronoforms

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I'm completely new to `chronoforms`.

I have **joomla 3.0** running on my localhost and installed the chronoforms script V4 RC3.3. I have already put some textboxes and stuff together in a form an everything works fine so far.

My problem is the `datetime picker`. I put the box in my wizard an changed it to mootools picker and vista style. No problem so far. But how can I change the output of the date format to dd.mm.yyyy?

I'm also use `"format: '%d %m %Y' "`, But i have **4 field start date, end date, start time and end-time.**

Above format is change all field, but i try to change only `date field`.
I searched forums and everything I tried doesn't work. It all ended in the format yyyy-mm-dd. So where do I have to change something to get the output I want?

Many thanks in advance to all who wanna help...

Comment: using id of the specific element and change the dateformat as per your need

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to new **Chronoforms V5** that already have a new Datepicker element. Edit your form, select **Design** tab, edit datepicker field and you will find selectbox called **Format** to choose the date format.

Comment: Just be aware that ChronoForms v5 installs along side ChronoForms v4 rather than upgrading v4 and you will need to recreate your v4 form(s) in v5. There is a BETA tool where you may be able to export your current form(s) from v4 and import them into v5, depending on the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var dp = new DatePicker("#yourid",{format:"%d %m %Y "});
```

Comment: what piece of line you added there

Comment: i'm insert your code after this code in my js.                     var DatePicker = new Class({

Comment: i think your are wrongly doing some thing,please refer to mootools date picker documentation